# SQL Server constraint check not working 

Tags: sql-server-2008, constraints

I'm using `constraint` to force business rule in sql server 2008 database as,

```
alter table TableName with check  
Add check    
(
    (col1 = 1 and col2 > 0)  
    or   
    col1 = 0  
)
```

when i try to execute insert query in Management Studio

```
update TableName set col1 = 1 where Id = 1; --the col2 =0 so it is not valid according to above constraint
```

after execute, i get the message `(1 row(s) affected)` without any error message!!

but actually when i check the data in table, it didnt change (which is right action).

Edit: so the unusual behavior is executed with `1 row(s) affected` although there is no row effected...

Comment: Can you verify in SSMS that TableName *does* in fact have that constraint in place?  That there was no problem in applying the contraint to the table?

Comment: ya, i verified.   
the constraint working fine in not update the the row but the problem that there is no any error message refer to that the update didnt apply, on the contrary, it display `1 row(s) affected`!!

Answer (score 0):

The question states that the constraint was created "with check," and you further state that the record with a "col2" value of 0 referenced in the UPDATE statement already exists. If the constraint that prohibits col2=0 was peformed "with check," it should have errored out at creation time on that very record, thus leaving no constraint in effect when you performed the update. That might explain the behavior you have witnessed.

Comment: it may not the problem (at least for now), because the query executed with message `(1 row(s) affected)` but in the real there is no any changes applied in the actual data of the table.   
the previous title may be more accurat, plz let me know what is the state, thanks.

Comment: What I am theorizing is that the constraint failed for some reason at *creation* time, thus was not present when you attempted the UPDATE. As a result, your UPDATE completed with the "1 row affected" result.

Comment: He is altering `Col1` in the update, so conceivably the row would pass the initial check.

Comment: Is it mean it is a normal behavior?    
executed with `1 row(s) affected` although there is no row effected...

Answer (score 0):

You can add `commit;` in order to commit your transaction

Comment: I didn't begin any transaction.
btw, i didnt get any errors and also the update statement didn't apply .